# ggplot negative sign in continues color scale does not align in center of text

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I was making a plot with `ggplot2` and to remove as much white-space as possible, I removed the spacing between the legend key and legend text. To my surprise the `-` sign did not align in the center of the text and makes it look like the text is miss aligned with the ticks on the color legend.

Are there any hacks that can properly align the `-` sign? It looks quite ugly to me as it is with the `-` sign almost aligned where the `.` is for indicating decimal.

Edit: Noteworthy, I am looking for a programmatic solution where breaks/labels/values does not need to be set manually each time.

##### MWE:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2
set.seed(1)
tibble(
  y = 1:10,
  x = 1:10,
  c = -runif(10)
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = c)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(.5, .5),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(.1, 'pt')
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: That's most likely got more to do with the font you're using than ggplot itself. Try similar text in a word processor with the same font (the default ggplot uses depends on your system) and see if the vertical alignment is about the same relative to the baseline of the characters. You could try finding a font that has the sign more centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could substitute the default minus sign using the arithmetic minus sign (unicode 2212). This can be done via a little lambda function passed to the `labels` argument of `scale_color_continuous`

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
tibble(
  y = 1:10,
  x = 1:10,
  c = -runif(10)
) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = c)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_continuous(labels = ~paste(ifelse(sign(.x) == -1, "\u2212", ""),
                                         sprintf("%2.2f", abs(.x)))) +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(.5, .5),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(.1, 'pt')
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! That looks way better.

Comment: I love that minus sign. Also worth pointing out that `scales::number(..., style_negative = "minus")` is a recent addition that also puts the typographic minus sign in front of negative numbers.